# Replacing button with image

Tags: html, css

I have successfully replaced the button with the image. But it appears that the image is placed on top of the button. I don't wish to put inside my CSS as there are other styles overlapping it and I don't want to have any redirect pages.

```
<button type="reset"><img src="images/cancel.png" width="15"></button>
```

Comment: `<button type="reset">`, do you mean `input`?

Comment: .... And why this question has "php" tag?

Comment: this <button></button> will give you a button. It actually same as input. Is just that if i change to input=image, it can't auto call out the reset feature of the button.

Comment: Why don't you simply use CSS with the button `<input type='submit/button'.../>` to make it look like an image?

Comment: (changed the tags from "php" and changed it to "html" and "css".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do this in CSS!

```
button {
  background-image: url(images/cancel.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  /* put the height and width of your image here */
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  border: none;
}

button span {
  display: none;
}
```

Then your button is:

```
<button type="reset" title="In some browsers, this appears as a tooltip"> 
    <span>Cancel</span></button>
```

You may also add specifiers to override default button behaviors - for example `-webkit-appearance: none;` but I believe that's enough to do what you need.

Comment: Can you kindly teach me on how to add a tooltip on top of the button in this case? Must i put inside my css?

Comment: @user976050 added a "title" attribute. For your purposes that probably will do the trick.

Comment: Hi, If i wish to have multiple reset buttons to reset different fields, i can't use this method ? Because now i have two reset buttons for two different fields. When i press either of the reset button, it will reset both.

Comment: I  believe that's a matter of binding your buttons appropriately to the correct JavaScript. I suggest creating a new question to ask that question separately.

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script>
        function change(thi) {
            debugger;
            thi.setAttribute("src", "guitar.jpg");
            thi.innerHTML = "";
            thi.outerHTML = thi.outerHTML.replace(/button/g, "img");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="change(this)">OUR BUTTON</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need the button?

You can try and remove the button tag and try either of these :

```
<img src="images/cancel.png" width="15" onClick="document.form1.reset();">
```

or

```
<a href="#" onClick="document.form1.reset();"><img src="images/cancel.png" width="15"></a>
```

Just replace "form1" with your form name.

Comment: can't do this way. Because I do not want to reset my whole form. There are other items inside.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="reset" width="15" style="background-image: url('images/cancel.png');"/>
```